# List all unique combinations of how items in different sets can be grouped. With varying number of sets and group sizes

Tags: c#

I need to be able to create a list of all possible valid combinations of groups of elements `(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>>)` from multiple sets of data so that:

1. Groups contain at least one item from at least one of the sets.
2. A single group cannot contain more than one item from a given set.
3. Repeat items (either within the same set or in different sets) are not considered to be the "same" item even though they might be "Equal" to each other. (so the solution shouldn't use Equality comparison).
4. Each item is in a group (potentially by itself).

I also have a fitness function to determine if a group of items is valid. If a group is invalid, any group that would contain the same elements would also be considered invalid.

- For example, if the group (1,2,3) is invalid, then the group (1, 2, 3, 4) would also be invalid.

**Clarification**

The function returns a level-3 collection, here's what each collection represents:

1. Innermost - a single group of related items. The fitness function is used to determine if all of the items in a group are related. Each group must contain at least one item, but cannot contain more than one item from the same set.
2. Middle - a collection of groups that have unique elements, whose combined contents is the same as the combined contents of all the input sets. (i.e. each element is used one and only one time).
3. Outermost - All possible combinations of groups.

For example, if I have two sets: [1, 2, 3] and [A, B, C], I would expect the following results:

- [1], [2], [3], [A], [B], [C]
- [1], [2], [3A], [B], [C]
- [1], [2], [3B], [A], [C]
- [1], [2], [3C], [A], [B]
- [1], [2A], [3], [B], [C]
- [1], [2A], [3B], [C]
- [1], [2A], [3C], [B]
- [1], [2B], [3], [A], [C]
- [1], [2B], [3A], [C]
- [1], [2B], [3C], [A]
- [1], [2C], [3], [A], [B]
- [1], [2C], [3A], [B]
- [1], [2C], [3B], [A]
- [1A], [2], [3], [B], [C]
- [1A], [2], [3B], [C]
- [1A], [2], [3C], [B]
- ...etc.

**What I've got:**

```
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>> PotentalGroupCombinations<T>(
           IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sets, Func<IEnumerable<T>, bool> groupValidator)
    {
        if (!sets.Any())
        {
            //if there are no sets, there is only 1 possibility (with no groups)
            return new List<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>> { Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<T>>() };
        }
        else if (sets.Count() == 1)
        {
            //with only one set, there is still only 1 possibility (each item in its own group),
            //since each 
            return new List<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>> { sets.First().Select(item => new List<T> { item }) };
        }
        else
        {
            var currentSet = sets.First();
            var otherSets = sets.Skip(1);
            var baseCombinations = PotentalGroupCombinations(otherSets, groupValidator);
            //Can't figure out what to do here...
        }
    }
```

Comment: sounds like something that will need O(n^2) at least.

Comment: I’m thinking the solution would be recursive, and the fitness function is applied when an item is appended to a group (from a recursive call). The fitness function is really restrictive, so if it is used well, it shouldn’t have a scaling issue.

Comment: I think you could start by normalizing your input. You state some rules for the input type, so I would create a type that resembles workable data first. When you have created a type that is strict enough, you can worry about the permutations or combinations. Also make sure that the names you give to the properties of the new type are readable. Right now enumerable<enumerable<enumerable>>> is so unreadable that it gives me a headache. After that; make methods that do one thing. Only use branching to call methods. In other words: Prevent putting logic inside if-conditions. Use separate methods.